# Update ListView items from GridView button onclick()

Tags: android, listview, button, gridview

In one activity I have one ListView and one GridView layout. GridView layout is populated with buttons on runtime depending on database content and onClick callback for every button is created.
I would like to update ListView with different items on every button click, but I'm stuck on how to update ListView from Button onClick.
Here is my code:

**BlagajnaActivity.class**

```
public class BlagajnaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridView myBtngridView;
    ListView racunListView;
    ArrayList racunList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Blagajna");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blagajna);

        DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription._ID,
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.ARTIKL,
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.KOLICINA_NA_SKLADISTU,
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.CIJENA,
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.TIP
        };
        String sortOrder = ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.ARTIKL + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.TABLE_NAME,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder
        );


        RacunListViewAdapter racun_adapter = new RacunListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.racun_layout, racunList);
        racunListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV_Racun);
        racunListView.setAdapter(racun_adapter);

        racun_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ArtiklData newBtnArtikl;
        ArrayList artiklNamesList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String artikl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.ARTIKL));
            Integer kolicina = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.KOLICINA_NA_SKLADISTU));
            Integer cijena = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.CIJENA));
            Integer itip = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.TIP));
            Boolean tip = (itip == 1) ? true : false;

            newBtnArtikl = new ArtiklData(artikl, kolicina, cijena, tip);
            artiklNamesList.add(newBtnArtikl);
        }

        CustGridViewAdapter adapter_btn = new CustGridViewAdapter(this, artiklNamesList);

        myBtngridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GV_Artikli);
        myBtngridView.setAdapter(adapter_btn);
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }


    public class CustGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<ArtiklData> artikli;

        public CustGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArtiklData> list) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.artikli = list;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return artikli.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Button btn;
            ArtiklData artikl = artikli.get(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                btn = new Button(mContext);
                btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = btn.getLayoutParams();
                p.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                btn.setLayoutParams(p);

                btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                btn = (Button) convertView;
            }
            String mybuttontext = artikli.get(position).getArtikl().toUpperCase() + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + artikli.get(position).getCijena() + " Kn";
            btn.setText(mybuttontext);
            btn.setTransformationMethod(null);
            btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            btn.setId(position);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new ArtiklBtnOnClickListener(position));
            return btn;
        }
    }
}
```

**ArtiklBtnOnClickListener.class**

```
public class ArtiklBtnOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final int position;

    public ArtiklBtnOnClickListener(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button BtnStisnut = (Button) view;
        String ArtiklCijena = BtnStisnut.getText().toString();
        String lines[] = ArtiklCijena.split("\\r?\\n");
        String name = lines[0];
        String linescijena[] = lines[2].split("\\s+");
        Integer price = Integer.parseInt(linescijena[0]);

        DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(view.getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] return_columns = {
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription._ID,
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.ARTIKL,
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.KOLICINA_NA_SKLADISTU,
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.CIJENA,
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.TIP
        };
        String whereClause = ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.ARTIKL + "=?";
        String[] whereArgs = {name.toUpperCase()};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.TABLE_NAME,
                return_columns,
                whereClause,
                whereArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        String artikl;
        Integer kolicina, cijena;

        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                artikl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.ARTIKL));
                kolicina = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.KOLICINA_NA_SKLADISTU));
                cijena = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.CIJENA));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement an interface in your Adapter and pass it to ClickListener and call method in interface in onClick

```
interface GridClickCallback{
  void onGridItemClicked();
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class CustGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private  Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ArtiklData> artikli;
private GridClickCallback callback;

public CustGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArtiklData> list,GridClickCallback callback) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.artikli = list;
    this.callback = callback;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return artikli.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button btn;
    ArtiklData artikl = artikli.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        btn = new Button(mContext);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = btn.getLayoutParams();
        p.width= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        btn.setLayoutParams(p);

        btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    }
    else {
        btn = (Button) convertView;
    }
    String mybuttontext=artikli.get(position).getArtikl().toUpperCase()+System.getProperty("line.separator")+System.getProperty("line.separator")+artikli.get(position).getCijena()+" Kn";
    btn.setText(mybuttontext);
    btn.setTransformationMethod(null);
    btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    btn.setId(position);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new ArtiklBtnOnClickListener(position),callback); //<-- pass it to click listener
    return btn;
}
```

ArtiklBtnOnClickListener

```
public class ArtiklBtnOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
private final int position;
private GridClickCallback callback;
public ArtiklBtnOnClickListener(int position,GridClickCallback callback)
{
    this.position = position;
    this.callback = callback;
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Button BtnStisnut = (Button)view;
    String ArtiklCijena = BtnStisnut.getText().toString();
    String lines[] = ArtiklCijena.split("\\r?\\n");
    String name=lines[0];
    String linescijena[]=lines[2].split("\\s+");
    Integer price=Integer.parseInt(linescijena[0]);

    DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(view.getContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] return_columns = {
            ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription._ID,
            ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.ARTIKL,
            ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.KOLICINA_NA_SKLADISTU,
            ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.CIJENA,
            ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.TIP
    };
    String whereClause = ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.ARTIKL+"=?";
    String [] whereArgs = {name.toUpperCase()};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.TABLE_NAME,
            return_columns,
            whereClause,
            whereArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    String artikl;
    Integer kolicina, cijena;

    if (cursor.getCount() == 1){
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            artikl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.ARTIKL));
            kolicina = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.KOLICINA_NA_SKLADISTU));
            cijena = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ArtiklData.ArtiklDescription.CIJENA));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
   callback.onGridItemClicked(); // <---- call it here
}
}
```

then in Activity

```
CustGridViewAdapter adapter_btn =  new CustGridViewAdapter(this, artiklNamesList,new GridClickCallback(){
  @Override
  public void onGridItemClicked(){
      // do modification to list 
   }

});
```

You can also pass data in method of interface if you want

Comment: This is brilliant solution. Thank you. It's working like a charm.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

in my adapter

```
public class CustGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private  Context mContext;
private  List<Elements> elements;

public CustGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Elements> list) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.elements = list;
}

//other methods here
//getView
//getItemId
//getItem

@Override
public int getCount() {
   return elements.size();
}

public void updateElements(ArrayList<Elements> elements){
    this.list.clear();
    this.list.addAll(elements);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

then in the listener of your button, you call

```
adapter.updateElements(newList);
```